# What happens to a padwan whose master died before the training is finished?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, jedi-training

In jedi order a padwan is trained under one master, at a time a padwan can not be trained under two masters and a master can not train two padwans.

If a padwan is having his training phase where he/she is not ready for the knighthood trials and his/her master died, what does jedi council or code do with the padwan? does he or she is "transfered" to another master? Does padwan has to stop training and his fate is sealed forever? Does any other high council member [like master yoda] manages to train that padwan until a new master is ready?

**Edit:** @GorchestopherH Has given a nice feedback with example

> There are lots of cases where we see strict Jedi rules regarding who can be trained, but we also see that rules are bent almost all the time. It's difficult to know what official policy is with counter-examples flying in its face. Consider Luke, the most popular example. Obi Wan trained him, then when he died, Yoda did.

This is the case where there are very few jedi remaining and they **have to bend the rules in order to survive**. But what about Galactic republic era, where Jedi order is strictly followed by their code?

Comment: There are lots of cases where we see strict Jedi rules regarding who can be trained, but we also see that rules are bent almost all the time. It's difficult to know what official policy is with counter-examples flying in its face.

Consider Luke, the most popular example. Obi Wan trained him, then when he died, Yoda did.

Comment: @GorchestopherH It can be counted as rule, but at that time jedi are about to be finished. They have to bend the rules if the order is to be survived. What about the case in Galactic Republic?

Comment: My feeling is that almost all matters that are out of the ordinary rigor are left to the discretion of the Jedi Council. Anakin, also a popular example of rule bending, was too old to begin Jedi training. The council then deliberated and decided that they would train him despite this. It'd be interesting to see if this case is addressed in a Jedi code. Being a peace-keeping force you'd think this was common enough to have a go-to solution.

Comment: Additionally, Anakin was supposed to be trained by Qui Gon, as Obi Wan ascended to Jedi Knight. Qui Gon died, and Obi Wan took Anakin as a Padawan. How much the Council approved of *that*, I have no idea.

Comment: @GabeWillard Anakin's training was not started at that time, he was supposed to be Qui-Gon's padawan, but he started training with obi-van instead. In that case what if Obi-Van died between ep1 and ep2 what should've been the fate of anakin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a Padawan lost their master under unusual circumstances, the situation would be evaluated by the Jedi Council. At that point, several options presented themselves:

- In most cases, the Padawan would be reassigned to a new Master, and would then continue their training under the new Master
- In cases where the Padawan was almost ready to take the Trials (this would normally occur upon the master's recommendation), special dispensation might be given to take the trials and earn the full rank of Jedi Knight
- If the Padawan were at fault (having killed their own Master), or was otherwise led to the Dark Side through the events leading to the Master's death, they would typically be taken out of rotation altogether and assigned to a special instructor (such as the [Dark Woman](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/An%27ya_Kuro)) for evaluation and re-training designed to bring them back towards the Light

***Note:** [Yaddle](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yaddle) would appear to be a unique case. Yaddle's master was killed about half-way through her apprenticeship. Yaddle herself then spent the next 200 years imprisoned within a cavern, with only the Force as her companion. The young Padawan continued her training on her own, growing greatly within the Force over the next two centuries. When released, she single-handedly helped the people of Koba rebuild from years of conflict, while also freeing the planet of its brutal Advose warlord. Upon returning to the Jedi Council, Yaddle was evaluated and ultimately promoted directly to Jedi Master, skipping the Jedi Knight rank/title altogether.

Yaddle's tale can be seen in Star Wars Tales #5 "[**Yaddle's Tale: The One Below**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yaddle's_Tale:_The_One_Below)". It has also been referenced in the novels [Cloak of Deception](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cloak_of_Deception) and [Jedi Quest: The Shadow Trap](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Quest:_The_Shadow_Trap).

Answer (score 4):

I guess (just my thoughts), that his training will be suspended and he will be set first in line for the next free master to continue his training.